# Should password reset tokens be in a separate table from the users table?

Tags: mysql, database

..or should I just go ahead and store them right in the users table even though they will mostly be null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For normalization reasons I would put them in a separate table.

```
table user
-------------
id integer primary key auto_increment
username varchar
salt_passhash varchar
......

table tokenreset
---------------
id integer primary key auto_increment
user_id integer
when_requested timestamp
all_done boolean default false
```

If you want to know the users that need to have their passwords reset do:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.email FROM user u
INNER JOIN tokenreset tr ON (u.id = tk.user_id)
WHERE NOT(tr.alldone)
```

Or code of that nature.

This way you will not have a field in `user` that does not get used 95% of the time.

Comment: gotcha, so even though it more or less won't matter since I'll have a tiny amount of users, I should stick to best practices.

Comment: This approach allows you to keep a log of password resets, just including a boolean field in the main user table does not allow that. For that reason alone I'd prefer a separate table. And I only need to query it if a password reset is requested and/or granted. So it does not get in he way with the normal running of the website.

Answer (score 1):

Either is a valid implementation. It really doesn't matter.

It's not like you're going to have enough users that you care about that extra bit per row to store the fact that the column is NULL. Even if you are Facebook.

Comment: yeah that's what I was thinking.  Thx for confirming.

Comment: I disagree strongly, esp if you want to associate extra data with the tokenreset event, like `when was the password reset`, `when was the email send`, `how many times did a user request a password reset` etc.

Comment: You can put all of those in extra columns; extra columns are cheap.

Comment: -1, Not only are you then **not** normalizing the table, you are wasting space, at no speed gain whatsoever. If you index the password reset related fields to speed up selection of a reset token, you slow down every single insert/update into the user table. This is just a complete waste of time and space. In the normalized example no speed loss during user insert/update occurs, there is no wasted space (you can clear out rows if you need the space). So the normalized example will be faster, smaller in space and give you more options. It simply does not have downsides.

Comment: If you were just talking about the 1 boolean column, I could agree. But putting in extra unnormalized columns willy nilly is madness and a clear anti-pattern.

Comment: It really doesn't matter enough. You aren't likely to want to index these columns, and even if you do, the index will be small and cheap (most values are NULL, right? so no index entry exists for most rows). Moreover, users is a small table which is mostly static, it's not going to have millions of rows (or if it does, then great for you!)